# How to ship the stylecop.json and custom.ruleset files with a NuGet package in VS2017

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, nuget, stylecop

At the moment we are switching from VS2015 to VS2017. One of our upgrade steps is to switch from stylecop to the new Stylecop.Analyzer package. The new Stylecop is using 2 files. The [stylecop.json](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/EnableConfiguration.md) and the Stylecop.ruleset.

**The target:** I want to provide the stylecop files as a custom nuget package. But I dont know how to create the needed .csproj entries.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
...
        <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>packages\My.StyleCop.1.0.0-pre15\RuleSet\My.StyleCop.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    </PropertyGroup>    
...
    <ItemGroup>
        <AdditionalFiles Include="packages\My.StyleCop.1.0.0-pre15\Config\stylecop.json">
            <Link>stylecop.json</Link> 
        </AdditionalFiles>  
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

In the past, there was the possibility to use a install.ps1 script to do this stuff. But with NuGet 3. (or 4.) the install scripts are obsolete and will be ignored.

I already tried to use My.StyleCop.targets:

```xtml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <AdditionalFiles Include="packages\My.StyleCop.1.0.0-pre17\Config\stylecop.json">
          <Link>stylecop.json</Link> 
        </AdditionalFiles>    
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

But here I have some issues, too. Since NuGet 3. (or 4.) there is no solution wide package folder and I dont know any variable or placeholder I can use here to get a absolute or relative path to my package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thanks to Paulo.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48874698/1153464)
How I did it:

This is the structure of my NuGet package.

[image]

The solution is quiet easy. You need to create to files. A .props and a .targets file named like the NuGet package and place them in the build folder of your package.

In these MSBuild files you can use the $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory) variable to get the path of your NuGet package.

```
MSBuildThisFileDirectory  = C:\Users\UserName\.nuget\packages\sig.stylecop\1.0.0-pre23\build\
```

My SIG.StyleCop.props file:

```xtml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\RuleSet\SIG.combiLink.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

My SIG.StyleCop.targets file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <AdditionalFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\Config\stylecop.json">
            <Link>stylecop.json</Link> 
        </AdditionalFiles>    
    </ItemGroup>    
</Project>
```

Cause of the structure of my package i need to navigate (..) into the Config and into the RuleSet folder.

Comment: Just checking, but do you really want to overwrite the CodeAnalysisRuleSet property?

Comment: In our case I think that is ok. We are shipping our own ruleset. I do not know if there is a function that can extend a existing ruleset.

Comment: I've tried your solution in a .Net standard 2.0 project, but I can't seem to wire the configurations. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `.props` or `.targets` files to the `build` folder in your packages and they will be imported to the projects.

On the `.props` file, you can use the `MSBuildThisFileDirectory` MSBuild variable that represents the folder where that file is located.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the hint I needed!

Answer (score 1):

The variable $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory) already includes the backslash at the end. It is important to omit the backslash when you reference the ruleset and the stylecop.json file:

`<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\RuleSet\SIG.combiLink.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>`

`<AdditionalFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\Config\stylecop.json">`

With the double backslash I experienced two strange problems in Visual Studio 2017:

- Unit tests rebuild the code each time I start them, even without any code change
- The IDE shows many StyleCop errors in the Error List window and shows red marks in the scroll bar even for rules that are explicitly disabled in the rule set.