# How to create nuget package with Stylecop Analyzer and custom ruleset?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, stylecop

I need to create a nuget package package with stylecop.json and something.ruleset with referencing to stylecop analyzer.
This package will be used across all the teams to standardize the rules for .net.
I have read this:

- [How to ship the stylecop.json and custom.ruleset files with a NuGet package in VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48870718/how-to-ship-the-stylecop-json-and-custom-ruleset-files-with-a-nuget-package-in-v)
- https://ngeor.com/2018/03/03/how-to-use-stylecop-analyzers.html

But unfortunately I did not properly understand how to achieve this. I have stylecop.json and .ruleset file. I have done the following steps:

- Added nuget package for Stylecop Analyzers
- Added the stylecop.json file to the solution
- Added the .ruleset file to the solution
- Added a nuspec file to the solution

May I please know what need to be done now to create the nuget package including the stylecop.json and .ruleset file?

[image]

Comment: You should use [nuget.exe](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) cli with `xxx.nuspec` file to pack your project. You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> May I please know what need to be done now to create the nuget package
>   including the stylecop.json and .ruleset file?

You should add some nodes about these files in the `xxx.nuspec` and then use [nuget.exe cli](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) with `xxxx.nuspec` file to pack your project.

**Since** you have generated the `xxxx.nuspec` file, you should add these in nuspec file.

**Solution**

**1)** You should add these nodes into `xxx.nuspec` file and with it, these files will be added into the new projects by nuget.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    .......

<contentFiles>
<files include="any/any/stylecop.json "(the relativepath of the file under the ContentFiles folder in the xxx.nupkg) buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" flatten="false" />
<files include="any/any/xxxx.Ruleset "(the relativepath of the file under the ContentFiles folder in the xxx.nupkg) buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" flatten="false" />
</contentFiles>
  </metadata>

<files>
<file src="stylecop.json(the relativePath of the file under the project)" target="contentFiles/any/any" />
<file src="xxxx.Ruleset(the relativePath of the file under the project)" target="contentFiles/any/any" />
<file src="stylecop.json(the relativePath of the file under the project)" target="content" />
<file src="xxxx.Ruleset(the relativePath of the file under the project)" target="content" />
</files>

</package>
```

**2)** Remember to use this function, you should use `nuget.exe` and  you should download it from the link and then set its path into **PATH** of system environment variable. For an example, the downlaod path is `C:\nuget\nuget.exe`, you should set `C:\nuget` in **PATH** and then yo can call **nuget** in CMD.

**Besides**, when you modify `xxxx.nuspec` file just I said above, you should first cd the path of your project and check whether the `xxxx.csporj` file exists under that path.

[image]

**After** that, you can use `nuget pack` in CMD to pack your project and then you will obtain a `xxx.nupkg` which is the nuget package.

[image]